# IP address using 3G/4G modem (USB on the go)

Tags: 3g, usb-on-the-go, carriers, ip-address, usb-modem

If I use a 3G USB (on the go) modem on my Android device, do I get the IP assigned by the Carrier as the SIM card was inside of the device?
Does it appear as usb0 in ifconfig?
Thank you.

PS
I would like to avoid what happens on the pc when you use usb tethering: the phone has its IP assigned by carrier (usually 10.*.*.*) while the pc gets a different address (usually 192.168.*.*) as in a local network with the phone only